# Smarty assign var to config file vars

Tags: php, smarty, variable-assignment, configuration-files

My question looks almost the same as this [Is it possible to put variables inside config files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3863310/is-it-possible-to-put-variables-inside-config-files)

I have a config file that controls the language. Also I have a feedback div that is showed for the feedback.

Now I want to assign feedback like this:

`$smarty->assign('feedback', 'the_age_of_user_' . $user->name . '_is_changed_to_' . $user->age . '_years');`

### nl.conf

`the_age_of_user_%s_is_changed_to_%s_years` = `De leeftijd van gebruiker %s gewijzigd naar %s jaar`

### en.conf

`the_age_of_user_%s_is_changed_to_%s_years` = `The age of user %s is changed to %s years`

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this? Or is there a better solution to assign variables to the config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but I don't completely understand what are you trying to accomplish.

In our project, we have following solution for similar problem:

Language file:

`the_age_of_user_is_changed = The age of user {user} is changed to {year} years`

Notice that there is no %s or any variables on left side. It is always constant.

**Option 1:**

1. Smarty/code assigment:
   `$smarty->assign("VARIABLE_TO_USE_IN_TEMPLATE", getLang('the_age_of_user_is_changed', array('user' => $user->name,'year' => $user->age));`
2. Then, in Smarty, you can use following code: `{$VARIABLE_TO_USE_IN_TEMPLATE}`

Function getLang reads string information from language files and replaces all {symbol} to corresponding data.

**Option 2:**

1. In template, we have smarty userspace function:
   `{LANG key='the_age_of_user_is_changed' name=$user->name year=$user->age}`
   Lang is actually calls function getLang from previous example.
2. In code you have to assign user: `$smarty->assign("user", $user);`. After that, smarty will do everything by itself.

Comment: Thanks, but in this way it is not dynamic. Feedback is used for all my applications feedback. So for example `File not found` does not have any parameters.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean "not dymanic" ? When you decide which feedback to give - at this point you should know what are variables for current answer. At this point, when you know variables, you can already generate whole feedback string and save it in variable $feedback, for example. Later you can assign this variable to smarty. There is no other options, if list of variables is completely random.